# Python ZipFile.testzip() accepts invalid ZIP files

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I am using the built-in `ZipFile` and it's [`testzip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.testzip) method to verify if some user provided zip files are valid.

Unfortunately ZipFile seems to apply additional heuristics, as it accepts for example ZIP files that don't directly start with the Zip header `PK\x03\x04`. Instead it seems to search the whole file for this header which is unwanted and thus also accepts ZIP files which start with binary "garbage" appended with a ZIP archive.

Is there a way change `ZipFile` in some sort of "strict" mode where it only accepts plain 100% valid ZIP files?

Environment: Python 3.6 (on Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just added the check that was actually missing in the Python ZipFile implementation: The file have to start with the ZIP file header magic bytes:

```
# test if the file has at least some bytes        
if file_size < 10:
    raise BadZipFile() # file is too small to be a valid ZIP file

with open(uploaded_file, "rb") as f:
    header = f.read(4)
    if not header == b'PK\x03\x04':
        raise BadZipFile()
```

Comment: Stefan Brüns, in an answer that will probably get deleted shortly, points out that "The `PK\x03\x04` signature would not match if the file is a self-extracting zip file. It also does not match if the zip file does not contain any files."

Comment: @joanis Self extracting ZIP files are by strict definition) not a plain ZIP file, therefore this is exactly what I want. Self extracting ZIP files are executable files with an ZIP file attached.

Answer (score 1):

The [testzip function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/62fa613f6a6e872723505ee9d56242c31a654a9d/Lib/zipfile.py#L1439) just tests that all files in the archive have a valid checkum.

Many checks are only done in the [open](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/62fa613f6a6e872723505ee9d56242c31a654a9d/Lib/zipfile.py#L1549) method, when actually opening a zip entry (not when opening the zip file).

I am not aware of a "strict" mode, but I have an idea: you could also consider invalid the zip files that contains no entries, or any entry that cannot be opened. Betting that the probability of mis-interpreting a file for a zipfile having an entry with a valid checksum and openable files is way less probable than mis-interpreting a file for a zipfile.

Comment: Are you sure you have interpreted the linked code correctly? I would interpret this code that it accepts ZIP files that contain additional data after the ZIP file. So the code is searching for the ZIP archive central directory end denoted by `b"PK\005\006"`. I was talking about additional data that is located before the whole ZIP file starts. Is it possible that Python does not check for the ZIP header at all? It defines `stringFileHeader` containing the ZIP magic header bytes but they are never used.

Comment: @JMax It looks like so, yes, the initial magic is only cheched when you try to open a file in the archive, during the .open call.

Comment: I fixed my comment according to this.